# Map function on a list in Standard ML

Tags: sml, ml, mosml

Based on this definition:

An append list is a (simple) implementation of the list abstract data type that makes construction cheap (O(1)), but makes destruction expensive (O(n)). The `'a alistNN` and `'a alist` types are defined as follows:

```
datatype 'a alistNN = Sing of 'a | Append of 'a alistNN * 'a alistNN
datatype 'a alist = Nil | NonNil of 'a alistNN
```

The `'a alistNN` type represents the “non-nil” append lists, while the `'a alist` type represents arbitrary (nil or non-nil) append lists.

Im asked to make a map function defined as:

```
fun alistMap (f: 'a -> 'b) (xs: 'a alist): 'b alist =
```

That performs a map on an append list.

I have it defined as follows:

```
fun alistMap (f: 'a -> 'b) (xs: 'a alist): 'b alist =
    case xs of
      Nil => Nil
    | NonNil xs => 
      let
        fun mapNN(f: 'a -> 'b) (xs: 'a alist): 'b alist =
           case xs of 
             Sing x => Sing (f x)
           | Append (ys, zs) => 
             let
               val ws = mapNN f ys
               val ts = mapNN f zs
             in
               alistAppend (ys , zs)
             end
      in
        mapNN f xs
      end
```

I keep getting clashing types, especially with:

```
Sing x => Sing (f x)
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner function `mapNN` is annotated with the wrong type. The constructors `Sing` and `Append` form values of type `alistNN`, not `alist`. So it should instead be annotated as follows.

```
fun mapNN (f : 'a -> 'b) (xs : 'a alistNN) : 'b alistNN = ...
```

There are a couple other issues with your code:

1. The line `alistAppend (ys, zs)` has type `'a alist` but the function needs to return something of type `'b alistNN`, so this will be a type error. As a hint to fix this problem, notice that you create values `ws` and `ts` but then never use them... ;)
2. Once you fix `mapNN`, you will have a type error on the line `mapNN f xs`, because it has type `'b alistNN`, but needs to be something of type `'b alist`.

In summary, be careful about the difference between `alist` and `alistNN`. These are two different types, with different constructors, and fundamentally different meanings!